# Install imagick on mac

Tags: php, macos, xampp, imagick, pecl

I need to install imagick extension for php. I have already installed Image Magick. Then I did "sudo pecl install imagick". After this I had such output in console:

> Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/imagick/php_imagick.h'
>   Installing
>   '/usr/include/php/ext/imagick/php_imagick_defs.h'
>   Installing
>   '/usr/include/php/ext/imagick/php_imagick_shared.h'
>   Installing
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so'

but as I'm using XAMPP, my extension dir( as I understand ) is /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626. So what should I do to make this working, I tried to put .so file in extensions dir and to add extension=imagick.so record in php.ini and to restart apache, unfortunately this didn't work. Forgot to mention, I'm using osX and XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

Did you install ImageMagick that is required to use imagick : [ImageMagick for MacOSx](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx)

Comment: yes, I installed Image Magick. And had no errors during installation process of both imagick and Image Magick

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Nodashi link: 
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx

Here are steps you can to follow since I'm same Mac developer.

To install imagemagick:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Successfully:

```
  /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-0: 1,487 files, 24.3MB
```

To install ghostscript:

```
brew install ghostscript
```

Successfully:

```
  /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.51_1: 671 files, 87.4MB
```

Find the magick:

```
which magick
```

Then:

```
/usr/local/bin/magick
```

Try to run it to test a image then you will find it works:

```
magick origin.jpg converted.png
```

So let's do it by PHP way

Create a new php file:

```
sudo touch magick.php
```

Enter the code which we will use the 'exec' function to run the magick program:

```
<?php 
shell_exec('magick origin.jpg converted_php.png');
?>
```

After that we run it by:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php magick.php
```

Great, we can see there is a image file converted_php.png !!

Comment: This is incorrect. The question is specifically about installing **Imagick** which is a PHP binding to **ImageMagick**, whereas this answer is about *"shelling out"* to command-line **ImageMagick**.